# Is there a way to sync tasker profiles?

Tags: sync, tasker

I use tasker on all of my android devices.  That includes my work and personal phone and tablet. They all pretty much run the exact same jobs but all I can find is some really rudimentary way of exporting a file to a very specific location.  it's pretty horrible.

Is there a way to sync changes between devices? Possibles add logic to profiles to just let profiles act if they are on specific devices.

Comment: Using auto remote plugin for Tasker is a good starting point